# How to copy the contents of files from a command line search into a single file?

Tags: files, cat, search

Copy the contents of all search results into a single file.
I don't want to copy the search result but the file contents of the search result.

For example my search result returned a list of 10 files then I would like to copy the contents of those 10 files into a single file (e.g `dump.test`).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep` and `xargs`:

```
grep -rlZ search-text some/dir/ | xargs -r0 cat > dump.test
```

`-l` is to list the files that contain at least one line matching the `search-text`. `-Z` is to print that line NUL-delimited so it can be safely passed to `xargs -0`.

`-r` to search in all the files inside `some/dir/` recursively.

POSIXly:

```
find some/dir -type f -size +0 -exec grep -q search-text {} \; 
   -exec cat {} + > dump.test
```

That will be less efficient as that means running one `grep` command per non-empty file.

Comment: Shouldent you use the >> to append to the file rather than > which will erase the content each time ?

Comment: when i try using the following command, I am getting the error:grep -rlz vishal*20140608* | xargs -r0 cat > mydump.test xargs: illegal option -- r
xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]
grep: illegal option -- r
grep: illegal option -- z
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: @user73352, as I said, that's for GNU `grep` and `xargs`. That won't work with other implementations of `grep` or `xargs`.

Comment: @Boogy, not sure what you mean. `dump.test` is open only once and that is made the standard output of `xargs` in the first one and `find` in the second. So all the output of those and their children will be included in there, there will not be any erasing/overwriting.